# PostgreSQL INSERT Other Table Row as Attribute

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    a A,
    type varchar
);
```

As you can see, one of the Table B's attribute type is A.

First, I insert a row in Table A with the following query

```
INSERT INTO A(id, name) VALUES(3241,'Item1');
```

Then, I need to insert a new row in Table B. How can I select a row in Table A when inserting a new row in Table B, to be used as attribute a value?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not a good idea. If you want to combine data from the two tables you should use regular reference, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id int REFERENCES A(id),
    type varchar
);
```

Still, it's formally possible what you want (however not recommended):

```
INSERT INTO B(id, A, type)
VALUES (1, (SELECT A FROM A WHERE id = 3241), 'some type');

SELECT * FROM B;

 id |      a       |   type    
----+--------------+-----------
  1 | (3241,Item1) | some type
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
INSERT INTO B (id,a,type) VALUES
    (123456,(SELECT A from A WHERE id=1234656), 'typeName' );
```